# What exactly is "logical justification"?

Tags: definitions

I read and hear the term "***logical*** justification" and I can't find a definition for it. Is it as pedestrian as it sounds (can be put in the form of logic and makes a valid argument), or is it a term of art? When a philosopher insists that there is no such thing as "empirical justification" and that the "only justification is logical justification", I'd like to know just what exaclty the latter is. I am concerned with the "logical" part of the term.

Answer (score 2):

> What is “logical justification”?

In philosophy the term [justification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_justification) usually is used in the context of :

> the justification of propositions and beliefs. [...] When a claim is in doubt, justification can be used to support the claim and reduce or remove the doubt. Justification can use *empiricism* (the evidence of the senses), *authoritative testimony* (the appeal to criteria and authority), or *reason*.

Thus, we may assume that “logical justification” means the justification of a claim by way of a deductive argument.

This means, inferring the claim (a proposition) from some premises with a valid [logical deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning).

Obviously, every argument needs [*premises*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premise): thus, the "strenght" of the logical justification supporting the claim depends on the level of certainty of the premises.

Comment: So I think you are saying that it's "can be put in the form of logic and makes a valid argument" as I suspected.

Comment: @DHD I know this is an old message, but you never got a straight reply, so I thought an example might help. A: "Your pen is on the table. [claim] I see a pen is on the table. It looks like your pen. (The support is specific to the claim.) Perception is widely agreed to accurately represent objective reality. (This explains that the support is accurate and matters.) [all of this is justification]" B: "That's not my pen. (Denying the claim.) It's blue, but mine is red. [justification] Maybe there's something wrong with your eyes. [counter to A's justification]"